# Identity Server4 Authentication Web API failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, identityserver4

I have an application that is broken up into 3 tiers.  I have Identity Server 4, a Web API and a C# Razor/MVC (.NET 5) application deployed separately all on the same domain.  There is a reverse proxy setup to route requests for each to their own server.  So [www.somedomain.com/IdentityServer](http://www.somedomain.com/IdentityServer), [www.somedomain.com/MVC](http://www.somedomain.com/MVC) and [www.somedomain.com/api](http://www.somedomain.com/api).

I am using Identity Server to authenticate and we can successfully do so without an issue.  However when I try to call one of the API endpoints (which are decorated with the [Authorize] attribute) from the C# Razor/MVC application I get a 'Authorization failed! Given Policy has not been granted' error.

When I run the same endpoint that the C# Razor app consumes using swagger/postman (after I've been authorized and get a token) I have no problem returning returning valid results, so the issue seems to be related my authentication between the Razor app and Web API.

When I run these 3 tiers locally in Visual Studio (all with localhost but a different port #), it all works just fine.

Any thoughts or additional information needed to give me some ideas of what the issue may be?  Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Compare the tokens: do they contain the same claims? Are you using `aud` (audience)? Are you requesting the right scopes in order to get the right audience claims? Are you setting up authorization (sic) policies? Or just roles?

Comment: I have compared the tokens between the deployed version and the localhost version and the claims are the same.  Yes, I'm using aud and they are the same as well.  I am using roles.  The only difference that I can see with the cookies between the deployed and locally running site is the there is a cookie that is being blocked in the deployed version which says "the cookies was blocked because it's path was not an exact match for or a superdirectory or the request url's patch".

Comment: All cookies path in the request is "/" except the one that is blocked which is "/IdentityServer" which is the url (www.somedomain.com/IdentityServer) we are using with the reverse proxy to route requests to a different server.